# What is the url.py file that opens home using wagtail?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm starting using Wagtail + Django.

Generally, in Django you set the `urls` path in a `urls.py` file.

However, I cannot find the url.py that says to my app, when users visits main domain (local `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`) show `home_page.html` view.

I'm following the [get_started tutorial](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html).

And used this command to generate the basic apps:

```
wagtail start elim
```

This generated: a) elim, b) home, c) search apps.

Only elim app contains a urls.py, but it doesn't set a path for home:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.core import urls as wagtail_urls
from wagtail.documents import urls as wagtaildocs_urls

from search import views as search_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^django-admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

    url(r'^search/$', search_views.search, name='search'),

]
```

This is my project structure:

[image]

> **So how does going to "/" open the home page???**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The home dir is served by wagtail internal mechanism. Scroll to the end of the file `elim/urls.py` to find this :

```
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + [
    # For anything not caught by a more specific rule above, hand over to
    # Wagtail's page serving mechanism. This should be the last pattern in
    # the list:
    url(r"", include(wagtail_urls)),

    # Alternatively, if you want Wagtail pages to be served from a subpath
    # of your site, rather than the site root:
    #    url(r"^pages/", include(wagtail_urls)),
]
```

So, continue to read the tutorial, I'm sure you will soon or later discover [the `Page` models](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/index.html) and everything provided by wagtail.

Comment: Wagtail beginner here too, so this `home` app is the default entry point to the website? And cannot be removed or replaced?

Comment: @avocado If you go to wagtail admin and navigate to Settings>Sites, you can see the root page which has been mapped to the site. By default, wagtail projects have a site with the home page mapped to the root page.

Answer (score -3):

Try adding a view function in your app's views.py file that renders home_page.html when the user goes to "/".

in views.py write this:

```
def home_page(response):
    return render(response, "home/home_page.html")
```

then map this to ur urs.py file

```
url_patterns = [
path("", views.home_page)
```

]

then add this url to your url conf

Comment: So it maps the url internally, but you can overwritte it like this?

Comment: like how i do it is that for each app i have it's own urls.py file where i make all the url_patterns for that particular app. Then i map that url_patterns from the urls.py file in my app to the main urls.py file in the settings app by using the include() function.

Comment: I tried and works. But I was asking how does wagtail does it. A part in the docs, or something more specific.

Comment: Sorry man I don't do wagtail...I'll upvote this so that more people can see this.